# How to close the main window in MFC dialog-based application

Tags: c++, mfc

Can anybody answer how to close the main window in MFC dialog-based application when I want to close the application itself? The application was created in MS VS 2010.
Thank you very much in advance.

Eugene.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
ASSERT( AfxGetMainWnd()!=NULL );
AfxGetMainWnd()->SendMessage(WM_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can send WM_CLOSE to your dialog hwnd. PostQuitMessage should also allow to end application execution.

Comment: But is there the member function of CWnd class for closing window?

Comment: CWnd::SendMessage will call ::SendMessage with hwnd from hwnd attached to this CWnd. Actually CWnd is a thin wrapper around WinAPI, most (if not all) its functions deletage its work to WinAPI using SendMessage

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what processing you want to happen as part of the shutdown. If all you want is to terminate the message loop without any further processing you can call `PostQuitMessage( exitCode )`. The `exitCode` will be stored as the process' exit code.

If you want to invoke the OK/Cancel handlers you have to call `OnOK()` or `OnCancel()` respectively. The default implementation for `OnOK()` will try to save and validate the dialog data and upon successful execution call `EndDialog( IDOK )` to terminate the message loop. The default implementation for `OnCancel()` simply calls `EndDialog( IDCANCEL )`. Neither one lets you specify an exit code for your process. If you have overridden either of those member functions you need to call the base class implementation after performing your specialized code, unless you wish to prevent shutdown.

Keep in mind that `OnOK()` and `OnCancel()` are protected members of `CDialog[Ex]` and cannot be directly accessed from outside. If you need to call either one from outside your dialog class you have to override them publicly. You can get a pointer to the main dialog using `CMyDialog* pDlg = dynamic_cast< CMyDialog* >( AfxGetMainWnd() );`.

Comment: I want to exit from application to OS. So I think that PostQuitMessage() will fit to this need. I'll try it.

Comment: PostQuitMessage() is nice! It fits the need and solves my problem! Thank you.

Comment: @user1688773 Consider reading the following FAQ: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).